# Joomla 3: How do I apply my own menu style

Tags: css, joomla, menu

I've built my own (simple) template. The menu module is like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="modHNavBar"  />
```

The CSS in the template.css file is like this:

```
.TopMenuItem {
    padding: 5px 15px;  
    background: #000063;
    color: #DEE7EF;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border: 1px solid #DEE7EF;
    float:left;
}
```

In order to style it, I had to select each and every menu item and apply the Link CSS Style from the Admin back-end.

This seems like a lot of work. Is there an easier way to simply apply the style to the whole menu?

Just for the record, the following does not work:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="modHNavBar" style="TopMenuItem" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of methods how to style the menu.

1. **Wrap the `<jdoc />` in div**: `<div class="TopMenuItem"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="modHNavBar" />`
2. **Use Menu class suffix**: Extensions > Modules > [menu module] > Options > Advanced Options > Menu Class Suffix / Menu Tag ID
3. **Use module chrome**: in your template folder create file `html/modules.php`, create `function modChrome_mymenu($module, &$params, &$attribs)` read more in documentation pages: [Applying custom module chrome](http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome), [Module chrome](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_chrome)

If you want to style each menu item individually, you may add class to each menu item:
Menus > Main menu > [menu item] > Advanced Options > Link CSS Style

or add css styles to like this: nav.menu .item-101 { background: green }

Comment: Many thanks for your inputs. I tried method 1 first. This means that I have to manually wrap every item. Otherwise the styles will apply commonly to the entire set of menu items and not to individual elements. But I think method 2 is better. For some weird reason method 3 did not work either. I tried it already. Thanks!

Comment: Check out method 4, I was not really sure what exactly you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla panel:
Menu -> Main Menu -> "Home", or some menu item -> Advanced Options -> Link CSS Style -> "home", or some name. -> Save

In the CSS:
`#nav ul li a.home{background-color:#4E5426; color:#FFFFFF;}`
`#nav ul li a.home:hover{background-color:#9A9B19; color:#FFFFFF;}`